# Como crear Relación entre usuario y materiales

Tags: mysql, sql

**El sql que tengo en mi Base de Datos**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.3.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 29-06-2017 a las 20:44:56
-- Versión del servidor: 5.6.24
-- Versión de PHP: 5.6.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `comunal`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `materiales`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `materiales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `materiales`
--

INSERT INTO `materiales` (`id`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, `cantidad`, `precio`, `total`) VALUES
(2, 'malla', 'a', 33, 100, 3300);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuarios`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(170) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `presupuesto` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `usuarios`
--

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `direccion`, `correo`, `pass`, `admin`, `presupuesto`) VALUES
(2, 'Gabriel', 'blanco', 'la romana maracay', 'luisgamez@hotmail.com', '123', 1, 3300),
(4, 'darwuin', 'gamez', 'paul', 'luis@hotmail.com', '12', 0, 3300);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `materiales`
--
ALTER TABLE `materiales`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `materiales`
--
ALTER TABLE `materiales`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: He entendido que quieres crear una relación entre las tablas `usuarios` y `materiales`. Bien, bien, esa relación podría ser una tercera tabla, casi seguro, que contenga los id de usuario y de materiales. ¿Has intentando algo en ese sentido?

Comment: no se nada de relaciones, no me dieron BD y e estudiado otros lenguajes y no la BD

Comment: lo que estoy tratando es una bd de inventario de facturacion donde la empresa puede ver a los empleados pero no los materiales que tienen y los empleados registran los materiales. El problema es que no hacer las relaciones entonces no se como hacer las funciones de eliminar  y modificar cualquier material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno, en realidad existen varios tipos de relaciones entre tablas, y según el caso aplicará una u otra.

Para el caso que nos ocupa creo que aplica un tipo de relación *varios a varios*. Ya que, supongo, varios registros de la tabla `usuarios` tendrán o podrán tener varios registros de la tabla `materiales` en la relación.

En ese caso lo mejor sería crear una tabla asociativa que registre las relaciones entre usuarios y materiales mediante los campos `id` en ambas tablas.

La estructura de dicha tabla sería muy simple:

```
-- Tabla para relacionar personas y materiales

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios_materiales` (
  `usuario_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `material_id` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

Dicha tabla debería indicar que no se pueden repetir varias veces los mismos valores para sus dos columnas, para evitar que haya duplicados. Pero eso sería muy fácil de hacer. Lo que presento es una estructura básica.

Cuando tengamos datos en nuestra tabla, podremos poner en relación `usuarios` y `materiales` con consultas como esta:

```
-- Usando tabla usuarios_materiales para consultar
-- los materiales de cada usuario

SELECT u.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(m.nombre SEPARATOR '|') as materiales 
    FROM usuarios_materiales um
    INNER JOIN usuarios u       ON um.usuario_id=u.id 
    INNER JOIN materiales m     ON um.material_id=m.id
    GROUP BY u.id
;
```

Lo que hace la consulta de más arriba es unir los datos de ambas tablas usando la tabla asociativa. A partir de ahí, es posible obtener cualquier dato de cualquiera de las dos tablas.

En este ejemplo obtienes todos los materiales de cada usuario en una sola columna, separados por `|`,  es como si fuera un array de materiales, que puedes leer desde PHP o cualquier otro lenguaje usando funciones como `explode`.  Puedes obtener así cualquier columna de cualquiera de las dos tablas.

Otros tipos de uniones `JOIN` son también posibles, dependiendo de tus necesidades.

Espero que al menos te quede un concepto básico de como poner en relación dos tablas.

---

#### `Ejemplo completo:`[`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/GJAJMH82556)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `materiales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `materiales` (`id`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, `cantidad`, `precio`, `total`) 
VALUES
(2, 'malla', 'a', 33, 100, 3300),
(3, 'otro', 'b', 34, 100, 3200),
(4, 'más', 'c', 33, 100, 3300);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(170) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `presupuesto` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `direccion`, `correo`, `pass`, `admin`, `presupuesto`) VALUES
(2, 'Gabriel', 'blanco', 'la romana maracay', 'luisgamez@hotmail.com', '123', 1, 3300),
(4, 'darwuin', 'gamez', 'paul', 'luis@hotmail.com', '12', 0, 3300);


-- Tabla para relacionar personas y materiales

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios_materiales` (
  `usuario_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `material_id` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `usuarios_materiales` (`usuario_id`, `material_id`) VALUES
(2,2),
(2,4),
(2,3),
(4,3),
(4,4)
;


SELECT * FROM usuarios;

SELECT * FROM materiales;
SELECT * FROM usuarios_materiales;


-- Usando tabla usuarios_materiales para consultar
-- los materiales de cada usuario

SELECT u.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(m.nombre SEPARATOR '|') as materiales 
    FROM usuarios_materiales um
    INNER JOIN usuarios u    ON um.usuario_id=u.id 
    INNER JOIN materiales m  ON um.material_id=m.id
    GROUP BY u.id
;
```

---

#### `Resultados`

```
  -- Datos en la tabla usuarios_materiales:

    usuario_id       material_id
    2                   2
    2                   4
    2                   3
    4                   3
    4                   4


   -- Datos de la consulta JOIN

    nombre        materiales
    Gabriel       malla|más|otro
    darwuin       otro|más
```

Answer (score 0):

También creo que la manera de crear la relación es creando una tercera tabla con las informaciones de ID_USUARIO e ID_MATERIAL que sera usada en el SELECT para poder hacer la relación entre ellas.
Si tienes el ID de material, haces un SELECT por ID_MATERIAL y recibes la info de el ID_USUARIO o al revés.

Comment: y como seria el tipo de relacion ??, es decir; los valores de la nueva tabla

Comment: La tercera tabla que menciona @Tiago, es la misma que esta en la respuesta de Cedano (tabla = usuarios_materiales ), y sirve para representar una relacion Muchos a Muchos entre la tabla de usuarios y materiales.

Comment: Como se almacenar el entero que representara la union, como es que se crear ese dato ? para poder unirlas despues

Comment: Como dijo Patrick, esta tabla es la de la respuesta de Cadeno, la verdad esta tabla te va a crear la relación entre los IDs, o sea, te a decir que el usuario 01 creo el material 04,08, 13... y el usuario 02 creo el material 02,33, 57... de la siguiente forma: USUARIO 01 | MATERIAL 04 , USUARIO 01 | MATERIAL 08 no retorno del SELECT. Con esto puedes buscar todos materiales de un usuario y poner en tu lista.

Comment: ya entendi , voy a probar

Answer (score 0):

**Lo que esta arriba esta correcto pero quiero llevar el SQL mas facil de entender, asi que estoy intentando esto:**

AQui cambie un poco la estruccura para entenderlo mas facil por motivo de urgencia, asi estoy haciendo pero no me ejecuta el echo, esta mal cierto

```
$datos = $conexion->query("SELECT u.id,m.id  
    FROM usuarios_materiales um
    INNER JOIN usuarios u       ON um.usuarios_id=u.id 
    INNER JOIN materiales m     ON um.materiales_id=m.id
");
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos);
    echo $user['u.id'];
    echo $user['u.id'];
    var_dump($user['u.id']);
```

**Esta Uniones Tengo que insertarlo para despues hacer la union ??**

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios_materiales` (`usuario_id`, `material_id`) VALUES
(2,2),
(2,4),
(2,3),
(4,3),
(4,4)
;
```

Comment: Según las normas del sitio, no puedes plantear 2 preguntas en 1. El objeto de tu pregunta era **poner dos tablas en relación**. Una vez resuelto, si se plantean nuevas dudas puedes abrir otra pregunta cuando hayas intentando usar tu consulta. Este **nuevo** problema concierne a PHP, no a MySQL. Sólo decirte que para obtener los datos de los resultados, en vez de: `echo $user['u.id'];` debería ser: `echo $user['id'];`, ya que en PHP lo que se usa es el **nombre de la columna** como sale en los resultados, no como lo usas en la consulta MySQL. O sea: `echo $user['nombre-de-columna-cualquiera'];`

Comment: _Estas uniones tengo que insertarlo para despues hacer la union?_ **Sí**. La tabla asociativa llamada `usuarios_materiales` será la tabla que se encargará de relacionar los usuarios y los materiales. O sea, en tu programa, deberás tener por ejemplo un formulario de entrada para agregar usuarios y materiales. En dicho formulario tendrías digamos dos `combobox` uno con todos los usuarios, otro con todos los materiales y un botón `Agregar`. Cuando seleccionas un usuario y un material y pulsas en el bótón, lanzarás un `INSERT INTO ...` que insertará el id del usuario y del material en dicha tabla.

Comment: gracias amigos .